# Not able to visualize linear regression with ggPredict

Tags: r

I have a data set called dataTreamill that contains 5 columns of text information, and row 6 until 56 contain the variables I would like to analyse. 
For every variable I would like to perform a linear regression to see how my data changes across different conditions.

I figured out that I could make a lm plot in the following way:

```
lmTreadmill = lm(StrideRegularity_AP~ConditionNr, data = dataTreadmill)
```

Visualizing this gives a nice plot:

```
ggPredict(lmTreadmill,se=TRUE,interactive=TRUE)
```

However as I have 54 other variables than StrideRegularity_AP I would like to use lapply

```
col <- c(6:56) # these are the only columns containing data; 
allFits = lapply(dataTreadmill[,col], function(x) (lm(x~dataTreadmill$ConditionNr+dataTreadmill$Group, data=dataTreadmill)))
```

Now I get a nice list for every variable with the information about the regression. 
However, when I want to plot any of these linear regression using this code:

```
ggPredict(allFits$StrideRegularity_AP)
```

Although when comparing allFits$StrideRegularity_AP with lmTreadmill (which are the same), I do not see any difference in structure or values, however R gives the following error:

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, yname, value = c(`1` = 0.616668527648763,  : 
  replacement has 419 rows, data has 30
In addition: Warning message:
'newdata' had 30 rows but variables found have 419 rows
```

Why am I not able to visualize the linear regression after using lapply?

Thanks in advance!
Iris

Comment: Try using `allFits = lapply(dataTreadmill[,col], 
     function(x) {  df <- data.frame(x=x, dataTreadmill[,c("ConditionNr","Group")]);  lm(x~ConditionNr+Group, data=df) }) `

Answer (score 0):

Drop the dataTreadmill$ from the lm call and try again.

```
allFits = lapply(dataTreadmill[,col], function(x) (lm(x~ConditionNr+Group, data=dataTreadmill)))
```

It's not needed as you specify the data anyway (and on a quick test with and without I get the same error as you - no idea why though)

Answer (score 0):

Both the solutions work! Thank you. 
Although I still wonder why, because the data looks completely similar to the suggestion I wrote. However, no at least I can plot the data :)